# Does it make sense to say "they didn't make it overnight" in the below sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> There are many people who make a lot of money per month but **they
> didn't make it overnight!**

Is that correct to say: **they didn't make it overnight?**
or maybe i can say:
They haven't reached there overnight
**or**
They haven't made it overnight

Comment: I think it's correct. Either meaning (during the night and suddenly [as in your sentence]) denotes a specific time interval (during the night and from the time they didn't make a lot of money to the time they started making a lot of money, respectively). I believe it justifies the use of the past tense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my judgment, your initial sentence seems correct, if you are trying to say: "they did not make all their money overnight".

It is saying "at no stage during their customary activity of making a lot of money every month did they ever do that over the course of one night."

To say "they haven't reached there overnight" sounds as though they are travelling somewhere in a car, perhaps, and they didn't get as far as they wanted to.

To say "they haven't made it overnight" seems to my instinctive ear the wrong tense to use. I expect someone with the necessary technical language will explain it.